# Is it possible to simulate miss call in Android emulator?

Tags: android

I have to do an Android application which should listen for miss call event. Is it possible to simulate this in Android emulator? Please help

Comment: from emulator control first call then hang it up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `DDMS` ,there you will get a tab called `Emulator Control` .In the textbox called `Incoming Number` input the number from you want to call by clicking on the `Call` button...Then call the `Hang Up` button...ie. the call is missed.
Hope it helps you.